# Exercício vetor, preciso de ajuda?

Tags: java

> Questão:Ler dois vetores: R de 5 elementos e S de 10 elementos. Gerar
>   um vetor X de 15 elementos cujas 5 primeiras posições contenham os
>   elementos de R e as 10 últimas posições, os elementos de S. Escrever o
>   vetor X.

Coloquei primeiro os valores do vetor r dentro do vetor x, mas de maneira alguma consegui colocar os valores do vetor s no x, de maneira que ficasse do 0 ao 4.

Ficou os valores do vetor r(Consegui), mas do 5 ao 14 não consegui por os do s.

Tentativa :

```
 int r[]=new int[5];    
    int s[]=new int[10];
    int x[]=new int[15];
    int a1=s.length-1,b=x.length-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite valores para o vetor R :");
        r[i]=dado.nextInt();    

    }for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite valores para o vetor S :");
        s[i]=dado.nextInt();    

    }for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    x[i]=r[i];  
    }for (int i =x.length-1; i >=0; i++) {
    x[b]=s[a1];
    b--;
    a1--;
      } 
for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    System.out.println("Vetor X indice "+j+" : "+x[j]);

 }
```

Comment: Mas poderia me ajudar na questão ?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está sobrepondo os valores.
Para resolver, você pode definir o `i` como 5, dai ele começaria a definir as variáveis a partir do 5º vetor.

```
for (int i = 5; i < 16; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite valores para o vetor S :");
    s[i]=dado.nextInt();
}
```